# Calling a function inside a PHP class from a function within the same class

Tags: php, class

I have some code below which will not run due to me not being able to know how to call a function that's within the same class as another function. I've already tried using `$this` but it gives me a PHP error `Using $this when not in object context...Line 25`. I have no clue how to fix this and I'm hoping someone else can give me some tips on what to do. My code is below, thanks :)

```
class SESSION {
    function start() {
        session_start();
    }
    function check() {
        if ($_SESSION["username"]) {
            return $_SESSION["username"];
        } else {
            return "nli"; //Not logged in :(
        }
    }
    function set_session($username) {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    }
    function login($username, $password) {
        $database = DB::connect();
        $passwordsha = sha1($password);
        $query = "";
        $res = $database->query($query);
        $num = $res->num_rows;
        if ($num == 0) {
            header("Location: login.php?e=1");
        } elseif ($num == 1) {
            $this->set_session($username);
            header("Location: admin.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: login.php?e=2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to run this statically?  Or are you actually creating an object and manipulating it?

Session::login($a, $b) vs. $pSession = new Session(); $pSession->login($a, $b);

Comment: Through other files I have used require() on this file to do `Session::login()` but in this case I need to call `set_session()` from `login()`. And no, I'm not creating the object.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Although there is no scope resolution (defaults to public), when you create a function within a class construct it becomes a method (still uses function keyword tho). The call to `$this->set_session` looks like it should work. What does the calling code look like?

Comment: @scjosh - If you're not creating an object, you're not creating a this.

The simplest thing to do is to use the function statically: "self::set_session($username)"

 -- HOWEVER, this is bad form.  You should mark your functions as static when they're static, or use them as object methods, never both.

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike: Lol it's weird looking at vanilla functions like this, took me a second to figure out what was going on.

Comment: You should not use classes that way. Normal functions do it pretty well for your needs.

Comment: why put them in a class if you are not going to use it as an object? just to namespace your global functions?

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to make a custom session handling class, but you're not using any of them here. However, the most egregious fault of your code is that it's using PHP 4 syntax when it should be using PHP 5 syntax, which would make the public/private/static definitions clear and it'd be much clearer what you intended with your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> And no, I'm not creating the object

This is why the call to `$this->set_session($username);` is failing, if you want to follow the same code pattern you have in place you can do this:

```
if ($num == 0) {
    header("Location: login.php?e=1");
} elseif ($num == 1) {
    self::set_session($username);
    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use login as class method, then you have to write like this:

```
SESSION::set_session($username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define  set_session  function as **private**. That way you can reference it using **this->set_session**

```
private function set_session($username) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
}
```